# EC2 Ubuntu Capistrano issue (NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "publickey":String)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, jenkins, capistrano

I've exhausted myself and my resources attempting to recreate what I must have miraculously created last week.

I'm using an EC2 micro instance running Ubuntu 12.10 x64 to create a test server for CI using Jenkins and Capistrano.

I was able to "figure out" what I was doing last week and have a server that seems to be working, but have found myself unable to recreate connecting to my EC2 instance to push the code from github to said instance.

Here is what I get when I rune "cap deploy":

```
jenkins@ip-10-170-102-174:/var/www/config$ cap deploy
```

* 2013-02-24 11:05:11 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-02-24 11:05:11 executing`deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-02-24 11:05:11 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:example/example.git master"
    command finished in 1871ms
  * executing "git clone -q git@github.com:example/example.git /var/www/example/releases/20130224110513 && cd /var/www/example/releases/20130224110513 && git checkout -q -b deploy de26b44bba59e1aa04dc3cf9dbec9dc4d9e4bdf3 && (echo de26b44bba59e1aa04dc3cf9dbec9dc4d9e4bdf3 > /var/www/example/releases/20130224110513/REVISION)"
    servers: ["example.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/example/releases/20130224110513; true"
    servers: ["example.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: example.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (NoMethodError: undefined method`each' for "publickey":String)
connection failed for: example.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "publickey":String)

Here is my deploy.rb file:

```
set :app_name, "example"
set :location, "example"
set :application, "example"
set :repository, "git@github.com:example/example.git"
set :user, "jenkins"
set :runner, "jenkins"
set :branch, "master"
set :port, 22
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :scm, "git"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = "publickey"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/var/www/jenkins"]
#set :default_stage, "dev"

role :app, "example.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", :primary => true
```

I need to note, I have followed several other forums and instructionals, and the key I generated called "jenkins" does allow me to connect to the server, working in /var/lib/jenkins - which makes this even more confusing.

I'm using the user Jenkins as I got that to work on my other server/it seems like it'd keep things simple for use with Jenkins.  I am new to this and am definitely trying to learn, I've read several articles, watched several videos, and am thoroughly frustrated and frankly, tired.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Mmm, no answer on this, I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a setup that started exhibiting the same behavior last week after an upgrade.  ([Looks like this has happened to a couple of us recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363003/amazon-aws-cap-deploycheck-fails/15375167#15375167).)

The error seems to indicate `[:auth_methods]` isn't assigned in a way that makes it iterable.

Try changing:

```
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = "publickey"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/var/www/jenkins"]
```

to this:

```
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["/var/www/your_actual_key_file.pem"]}
```

Comment: It ended up being an ssh authentication issue (I figured it out a few days after this post - what a nightmare).  Thank you!

Comment: set :user, "ubuntu" I had the same problem just tried some username and then it worked