# Amazon AWS, cap deploy:check fails

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm trying to setup deployment to an AWS EC2 instance, using capistrano. In order to test, I'm using

```
cap testing deploy:check
```

but Capistrano fails with:

```
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2013-03-12 15:41:27 executing `testing'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy:check'
  * 2013-03-12 15:41:27 executing `multistage:ensure'
  * 2013-03-12 15:41:27 executing `deploy:check'
  * executing "test -d /......./releases"
    servers: ["ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
    connection failed for: ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    (NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "publickey":String)
```

I'm using my .pem file to connect, and the deploy.rb script looks as follows:

```
set :stages, %w(production testing)
set :default_stage, 'testing'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, 'app_name'
set :user, 'the_user'
set :group, 'the_group'

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:......./#{application}.git"
set :deploy_to, '/......./'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# Authentication setup
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = 'publickey'
ssh_options[:keys] = ['~/........pem']
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your public key on the server.

And remove

ssh_options[:auth_methods] = 'publickey'

ssh_options[:keys] = ['~/........pem']

It should work

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded a development server and saw the same behavior.  The error message looks as though Capistrano is expecting an iterable and the assignment for `publicKey` isn't defining it as such.

As trivial as it may sound, try changing:

```
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = 'publickey'
ssh_options[:keys] = ['~/........pem']
```

to:

```
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/......pem"]}
```

You may need to do the same for the other items in your authentication setup.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = 'publickey'
```